# Dumpbin show function names

Tags: disassembly

Is there any way I can use `dumpbin` like `objdump`, where I can just look at the functions machine instructions that I implemented in my `Source.c` file, which I compiled to `source.exe`?
If I use `dumpbin \DISASM` with the section `.text` it shows me a lot of machine instructions, but it's impossible to find the machine instructions I am looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could utilize debug symbols to search for the disassembled code of interest. Here's a TL;DR from `dumpbin`'s docs:

1. `dumpbin` [always searches for embedded symbols](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/disasm?view=msvc-170#remarks) within the file:

> The /DISASM option displays disassembly of code sections in the file. It uses debug symbols if they are present in the file.

2. `dumpbin` tries to [load debug symbol information](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/nopdb?view=msvc-170#remarks) for the disassembled binary (works with PDB, no information on support for DWARF and other formats):

> By default, DUMPBIN attempts to load PDB files for its target executables. DUMPBIN uses this information to match addresses to symbol names.

If your `source.exe` was compiled with MSVC, simply put `.pdb` file in the same directory and use:

```
dumpbin /DISASM source.exe
```

The output will have symbol names applied - example disassembly fragment:

```
??$?6U?$char_traits@D@std@@@std@@YAAEAV?$basic_ostream@DU?$char_traits@D@std@@@0@AEAV10@PEBD@Z:
  0000000140011870: 48 89 54 24 10     mov         qword ptr [rsp+10h],rdx
  0000000140011875: 48 89 4C 24 08     mov         qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx
  000000014001187A: 55                 push        rbp
  000000014001187B: 57                 push        rdi
  000000014001187C: 48 81 EC 28 02 00  sub         rsp,228h
                    00
  0000000140011883: 48 8D 6C 24 20     lea         rbp,[rsp+20h]
  0000000140011888: 48 8D 7C 24 20     lea         rdi,[rsp+20h]
  000000014001188D: B9 52 00 00 00     mov         ecx,52h
  0000000140011892: B8 CC CC CC CC     mov         eax,0CCCCCCCCh
  0000000140011897: F3 AB              rep stos    dword ptr [rdi]
  0000000140011899: 48 8B 8C 24 48 02  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rsp+248h]
                    00 00
  00000001400118A1: 48 8B 05 58 B7 00  mov         rax,qword ptr [__security_cookie]
                    00
  00000001400118A8: 48 33 C5           xor         rax,rbp
  00000001400118AB: 48 89 85 F8 01 00  mov         qword ptr [rbp+1F8h],rax
                    00
  00000001400118B2: 48 8D 0D AA 17 01  lea         rcx,[140023063h]
                    00
  00000001400118B9: E8 11 FB FF FF     call        @ILT+970(__CheckForDebuggerJustMyCode)
  00000001400118BE: C7 45 04 00 00 00  mov         dword ptr [rbp+4],0
                    00
  00000001400118C5: 48 8B 8D 28 02 00  mov         rcx,qword ptr [rbp+228h]
                    00
  00000001400118CC: E8 79 F8 FF FF     call        @ILT+325(?length@?$_Narrow_char_traits@DH@std@@SA_KQEBD@Z)

...
```

If you find decorated names confusing, you can use [`undname`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/decorated-names?view=msvc-170#Undecorated) to decipher decorated/mangled symbol names into their signatures:

```
undname <decorated name>
```